# upload more than 200 images using php and html input tag

Tags: php

i'm trying upload multiple image files in php.i edited the php.ini and set upload_max_files to 20000.but it only uploads 200 images at one time.any help will be appriciated.

here's my code

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){ $count=0; foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){

    $target="upload/photo/";
    $target=$target.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $partphoto = substr("$target", 13, -4);
    $qq="select * from idol_student_photo where name='$partphoto'";
    $res=mysql_query($qq);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if(file_exists($target))
    {
    echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key]." already exists in photo folder <br />";
    }
    else if($row['name'])
    {
    echo $partphoto." already exists database <br />";
    }
    else
    {

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target)){
            //$id = mysql_insert_id($con);


            mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('$partphoto')");
            $count=$count+1;

        }
        }
}




            echo "<center>".$count."file uploaded</center>";
            }
```

Comment: Hey, I won't answer your question but I want to warn you that you're vulnerable to sql injections. Please read up on them or you will most likely get brutally hacked.

Comment: Why? Modern PHP system have the multiple statements disabled. So they can only insert stuff you dont want. It's not that brutally...

Comment: set these values in your php.ini max_file_uploads, post_max_size

Comment: also try using a plugin like uploadify.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a PHP Limitation. So we can't really help you with that. However; most PHP system do have a zip function. So detect if there are too much pictures in you clientside validation and suggest using the zip method to a user. I haven't tested this code, but should put you in the right direction!

```
$zip = zip_open("/tmp/youruploaded.zip");
$target="upload/photo/";

if ($zip) {
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {


        $zipfilename = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        $target=$target.$zipfilename;
        $partphoto = substr("$target", 13, -4);
        $qq="select * from idol_student_photo where name='$partphoto'";
        $res=mysql_query($qq);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
        if(file_exists($target)) {
            echo $zipfilename." already exists in photo folder <br />";
        } else if($row['name']) {
            echo $zipfilename." already exists database <br />";
        } else{

        $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));

            if (file_put_contents(￼$target, $buf)) {
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('$partphoto')");
                $count=$count+1;
            } else {
                echo 'can\'t put picture';
            }
        }
    }
    zip_close($zip);
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Sorry buddy, should be file_get_contents

Comment: Warning: zip_read(): 5 is not a valid Zip Directory resource in C:\wamp\www\test1\upload.php showing this and Warning: file_get_contents(uphoto) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied  this warning.

Comment: You know you have to handle the upload first right? Mate, SO isn't just a writemescript.com site....

Comment: all the uploaded images are of 1KB and they are not displaying correctly